# Add model to @url.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model:

```
public class Menu
{
    public Menu MenuEntity {get;set;}
    public List<Menu> MenuList {get;set;}
    public int MenuId {get;set;}
    public int? ParentId{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    public string Levelstate{get;set;}
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

In View I am using @Url.Action as below.

```
<a href ='@Url.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer")'>@citem.Title</a>
```

I want to change the Action and Controller specified in @Url.Action with model values, something like this:

```
<a href ='@Url.Action(m => m.Action, m => m.Controller)'>@citem.Title</a>
```

Comment: You cant use expressions in the `@Url.Action()` method, but you could use `@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.Controller)` - or it might be `citem.Action` if this is in a loop?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Any way to use Html.ActionLink ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Even @Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.Controller) is not working. After Model. there are only methods.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(citem.Title, citem.Action, citem.Controller)` (I'm guussing your have something like `foreach(var citm in Model) {`)

Comment: `Model.Action, Model.Controller` would not work if you model is `IEnumerable<Menu>` which I'm guessing it is (it would need to be `citem.Action, citem.Controller`)

Comment: Ok this is working: <a href ='@Url.Action(@citem.Action, @citem.Controller)'>@citem.Title</a> but it is not opening controller when used this way. Instead when I hardcode action and controller it is working.

Comment: Are you sure the values of properties `Action` and `Controller` are correct - i.e. `Action = "GetCustomer";` and `Controller = "Customer";`? Note you do not need the `@` in front of `citem`

Comment: Yes it is working now. Thanks. Please post your fourth and fifth comments as solution so that I can mark as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Url.Action()` method only accepts strings as its parameters, not an expression.

You can use

```
@foreach(var citem in Model) {
  <a href ='@Url.Action(citem.Action, citem.Controller)'>@citem.Title</a>
}
```

or using `@Html.ActionLink()`

```
@Html.ActionLink(citem.Title, citem.Action, citem.Controller)
```